# laravel with eloquent I am getting search error

Tags: laravel

I want to search by customer code in collection table. I get the following error. Can you help with this

Eror message;

> Property [Collection] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
$cut = Cut::with('cutStatus', 'Collection', 'CollectionOrder', 'CollectionOrder.collectionColor')
        ->orderBy('end_date', 'DESC')
        ->where('cut_status_id', 3)
        ->get();

    if ($request->search){
        //i am getting the error here
        $cut = $cut->Collection->where('customer_code', 'LIKE', "%".request('search')."%");

    }

    $cut_list = [];

    foreach ($cut as $cut_item){
        foreach ($cut_item->CollectionOrder as $collection_order_item){

                $cut_list['cut_list'][$cut_item->id]['cut_info'] = $cut_item;
                $cut_list['cut_list'][$cut_item->id]['color'][$collection_order_item->collectionColor->color_name] = $collection_order_item;
                $cut_list['cut_list'][$cut_item->id]['cut_piece'] = $this->CutPiece($cut_item->id);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Collections don't have a property named `Collection` ... is there a reason you are trying to access such a property?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Collection` relation on an array that's why you are facing this issue. You have to use use loop for specific result or get signle entry and apply relation.

Using Loop.

```
foreach($cut as $c)
{
    dump($c->->Collection->where('customer_code', 'LIKE', 
    "%".request('search')."%"));
}
```